# Warning UA0002: Type Controller should be replaced with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I need help in understanding why this warning appears:
"C:\Some\Path\src\Some\Application\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Views_SommeViewName_Edit_cshtml.g.cs(251,13): error UA0002: Type Controller should be replaced with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller [C:\Some\Path\src\SomeApplication\SomeApplication.csproj]"
I have treat warnings as errors enabled, that why is telling error and not warning.

Context: I have an ASP Net Core MVC application migrated to net6.0, that is when this warning has appeared.
A portion of my csproj:

```
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework><GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile><Nullable>enable</Nullable><TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors><ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
```

And this package reference:

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Humanizer" Version="2.8.26" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.0">
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.UpgradeAssistant.Extensions.Default.Analyzers" Version="0.3.256001">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.0" />
```

Rest of csproj is made of project references.

Things I've tried:
Used Google, DuckDuckGo with various search criteria.
Reviewed the migration guide.
And here stops any idea. It's clear that I'm missing something.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not show us the code that generates this error?

Comment: Is in a cshtml.g.cs file. i can't find the folder in the given path, I can't find the view in question or this part of the path "\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator".